# Everyone dropdown value unique not same value from three dropdown box jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying three drop down box value not same otherwise show error i tried but not working.anyone can resolve this issue?

Example:

correct scenarios:

Examples:-

Dropdown one value: 1
Dropdown one value: 2
Dropdown one value: 3

---

Dropdown one value: 3
Dropdown one value: 1
Dropdown one value: 2

---

Wrong Scenarios:

Examples:-

Dropdown one value: 1
Dropdown one value: 1
Dropdown one value: 2

---

Dropdown one value: 1
Dropdown one value: 2
Dropdown one value: 2

---

Dropdown one value: 3
Dropdown one value: 3
Dropdown one value: 2

If i select two time same value from the dropdown i want to show error.Everyone dropdown value unique otherwise want to show error.

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/5vw7Ljso/1/

```
$('#checkDate').bind('click', function() {  
   var one=$('#one').val();
   var two=$('#two').val();
   var three=$('#three').val();    
   if( (one==two) || (two==three) || (three == one)  ){

   }
   else{
      alert("error")
   }   
});
```

Comment: change all the  || to &&. The logic is wrong

Comment: @JordanMaduro:   Can you edit jsfiddle?

Comment: @JordanMaduro: Not working http://jsfiddle.net/5vw7Ljso/2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hm46k1dp/ Here you go. Unless I didnt understand. But If a user selects two the same values then it shows the error message. If they are all different then he gets ok.

Only problem is that in this code the user always has to select 3 values. Did you want to allow the user to select just 1 value?

Comment: user always can  select  values..no need restriction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the check you want. I add your selects to an array. Then I filter out the default value. The boolean filter is actually only necessary when you get an empty value.
Then I filter the array checking for duplicates. lastly, compare the length of the two arrays.

http://jsfiddle.net/nctaz5ox/

```
$('#checkDate').bind('click', function() {

   var one = $('#one').val();
   var two = $('#two').val();
   var three = $('#three').val();
   const values = [one, two, three].filter(i => 'Select' !== i)
   const filtered = values.filter((v, i) => values.indexOf(v) === i)
   if (values.length) {
     if (values.length === filtered.length) {
       alert("Ok")
     } else {
       alert("You can not select same value again..Please select different value")
     }
   }


 });
```

Comment: Your code is working fine..But can you do it instead of filter because some browser issue will come if we use filter

Comment: One more thing..initially no need alert message..bcoz i did select any values..alert message only need after i selected same values

Comment: @cinnan Updated answer and jsfiddle.

Comment: Thank you so much..working fine. but you did not removed filter